# How to call a value of an object property from a class in a text box?using VBA

Tags: class, vba, properties

I have the following property in my clsdata class:

```
Public Property Get PatientCount() As Long
   PatientCount = UBound(maobjPatient)
End Property
```

I also have this function in my class:

```
Private Function CountNonEmptyLines(ByVal strfile As String) As Long
   Dim intFile As Integer
   Dim strLine As String
   Dim lngcount As Long

   intFile = FreeFile
   Open strfile For Input As intFile

   lngcount = 0&
   Do While Not EOF(intFile)
       Line Input #intFile, strLine
       If Len(strLine) > 0 Then
           lngcount = lngcount + 1
       End If
   Loop

   Close #intFile

   CountNonEmptyLines = lngcount
End Function
```

the code of InputData is the following:

```
Public Sub InputData()
Dim blnLoaded As Boolean
Dim path As String
Dim file As String
Dim lnglines As Long

path = MyForm.TextPath
file = MyForm.TextFile

If LoadData(path, file) = False Then
    MsgBox FileErrorString
Else
    blnLoaded = LoadData(path, file)
End If

End Sub
```

and the code of LoadData is:

```
Private Function LoadData( _
ByVal strPath As String, _
ByVal strfile As String) _
As Boolean

Dim strPathFile As String
Dim lngRows As Long

LoadData = False

EraseData
InitialiseState

strPathFile = strPath & "\" & strfile
If Not FileExists(strPathFile) Then
    Exit Function
End If

lngRows = CountNonEmptyLines(strPathFile)
If lngRows = 0 Then
    Exit Function
End If

If Not LoadPatientLines(strPathFile, lngRows) Then
    Exit Function
End If

mFileError = leNOERROR
LoadData = True
End Function
```

In my form I have a button which loads some data from a file:

```
Private Sub CmdLoad_Click()
   Dim myData As New clsData
   Call myData.InputData   
End Sub
```

I also have a textbox:

```
Private Sub TextEntries_Change()
End Sub
```

How can I have the value of PatientCount or the lngcount from countnonemptylines function, in my textbox when I click CmdLoad, something like TextEntries.text=...?

Comment: `TextEntries.text = myData.PatientCount`?

Comment: thank so much, I have no clue about classes and I spend like 2 hours...

Comment: If I wanted to show the CountNonEmptyLines what should I change? I tried to change the function into public and then write TextEntries.text = myData.CountNonEmptyLines but I get an argument not optional error.

Comment: the same..`TextEntries.text = CountNonEmptyLines("file_path")`

Comment: I get an error 75, path/file access error.

Comment: check this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264531(v=vs.60).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As follow up from comments, this one works:

```
TextEntries.text = myData.PatientCount
```